# Specify layout in res.render() while also feeding it data

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have this code:

```
res.status(200).render('body_loggedin', usernameDocs[0]);
```

to render the data from `usernamedocs[0]` into the `'body_loggedin'` view but I don't want it to to have the main layout. Every answer to similar questions doesn't address this.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you using express-handlebars?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I should have noted that! @NikKyriakides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an options object, specifying the layout:

```
res.render('foo-template', { layout: 'foo', data: 'bar' })
```

Comment: I've tried this but I cannot figure out how to give 'foo-template' my usernamedocs[0] data if I do that.

Comment: Pass them as `data` in the options object. Let me edit.

Comment: That was exactly what I am looking for!! I will try it out right now.

Comment: @Danjuro Small note: It's not mandatory that you use `data` as the key here. You can pass any property/value pair you want.

Comment: Do you mean that 'data' could be any name and it would still work? If so, how does it know what to do?

Comment: Probably makes the entire object available. I'd bet if you attempted to print `layout` it would print out "foo".